# Recommended jQuery templates for 2012?

Tags: jquery, html, json, templates

jQuery Templates have been deprecated for some time now.

I have some data in the form of a JavaScript object that I want to format as HTML and append to the DOM. What's the best way of doing that these days?

1. Should I build up an HTML string?
2. Should I create elements via jQuery such as `$('<li>',{id:'my-'+Id}).append($('<span>').text(myText))` ?
3. Is there a replacement or mature substitute for jQuery templates?

Comment: [The API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) are apparently even more deprecated, they say that feature is "in beta".

Comment: @bfavaretto: Yep. Says [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl) they're not taking it past beta.

Comment: Some performance test [results](http://jsperf.com/2dom-manipulation-js-templating-vs-programatic-jquery) for your three options.

Comment: Apparently I'm not allowed to answer a question that's been marked as a dupe, but if you're already using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#template) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template), you can use their `_.template` functions. It's simple and supports escaping.

Answer (score 104):

This is how I do it in my projects:

Define a template in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="cardTemplate">
<div>
    <a href="{0}">{1}</a>
</div>
</script>
```

Use string.format to substitute variables:

```
var cardTemplate = $("#cardTemplate").html();
var template = cardTemplate.format("http://example.com", "Link Title");
$("#container").append(template);
```

[string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format):

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
  var args = arguments;
  return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
    return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
      ? args[number]
      : match
    ;
  });
};
```

Pretty simple, you can even combine templates.

Comment: How do you escape HTML where necessary? In your example if `{0}` contained a double-quote you just blew up your HTML.

Comment: @Mark You could call `escape()`. I'd definitely look for something more robust if I needed to do more than a few small templates. I just put it here as an example of something that might be useful, as it has been to me.

Comment: awesome.. one doubt though.. why it needs to be put under <script type="text/template" id="cardTemplate">

Comment: It doesn't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script

Comment: Tom Gruner has a nice snippet for escaping HTML from mustache.js here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Answer (score 10):

You should definitely try [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) and/or [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

I tend to use Handlebars but the syntax is quite similar.

Answer (score 9):

Mustache.js is quite good for templating.

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Answer (score 7):

Templates all the way, so much easier than trying to parse the JSON manually. Since I contributed to it, I'm partial to json2html as it doesn't require compiling of the templates AND uses nothing but JSON and JavaScript.

http://json2html.com

Comment: Out of the others mentioned here I like this the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realy don't like to build html element using javascript so I suggest you to use some template.
You can find a list of templates and a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449780/recommended-javascript-html-template-library-for-jquery).

I used to use `jQuery Templates`, it's prety simple but it's no longer actively.

Comment: If another question addresses this issue, you should just vote to close...

Comment: @sachleen As I said, it's not the same question. It's a related question. This question is about the best way to do it.