# wrap a html structure around a text

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

Given some text and a html structure, how can I create a new html fragment where the structure is wrapped around the text?

Example:

```
text = "mytext"
html = "<div><p><span></span></p></div>"
```

Desired result:

```
newHtml = "<div><p><span>mytext</span></p></div>"
```

If possible, using pure jquery, without parsing html manually. Note that "text" is a literal string, not a text node in a document.

Of course, the code I'm looking for should work with arbitrary html, not just with the example above.

Comment: Something like `$("<div><p><span></span></p></div>").find('*').last().text('foo')`?

Comment: @Blender: yes, something like this... any simpler solution?

Comment: Simpler? There's no `.insertTextIntoDeepestDescendant()` method...

Comment: I think @Blender's approach is about as simple as it comes. You could combine the `*` and `last`, but it's essentially the same: http://jsfiddle.net/MnJkE/4/

Comment: are you always going to insert the text between span elements?

Comment: @billyonecan: ok, for a lack of a better option, could you make this an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Blender for this (posting as an answer as requested):

```
text = "mytext"
html = "<div><p><span></span></p></div>"

newHtml = $(html);
newHtml.find('*:last').text(text);

console.log(newHtml.get(0)); // <div><p><span>mytext</span></p></div>
```

So construct a jQuery object from the `html` string, then find the `:last` descendent (in this example, the `span`), and set the `text`.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MnJkE/4)

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of :

```
var text = "mytext";
var html = "<div><p><span></span></p></div>";
var div = $(html);
div.find('span').html(text);
div.appendTo(someOtherElement);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works with my specific example. I'm looking for a more general approach.

Comment: I think you're looking into templates, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062368/new-recommended-jquery-templates

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
var text = "mytext",
    mainDiv = $("<div/>"),
    para = $("<p/>"),
    span = $("<span/>", {"html":text});

mainDiv.append(para.append(span));

//or you can write all above in one liner
```

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .wrap() in jQuery?
Try

```
    $('span').wrap(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the help of place holder as follows,

```
text = "mytext"
oldHtml = "<div><p><span>[0]</span></p></div>"
newHtml = oldHtml.replace("[0]",text);
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about something like this, but it doesn't work for my needs (html comes from outside, I can't insert any placeholders there).

Comment: Ok ill get back to u on this.
are you always going to insert the text between span elements?

Comment: No, not always. There can be any html.

Comment: So how will you come to know where u want to insert the text?

Comment: The text will be inserted in the bottommost node, just like in `$.wrap`