# asp.net request.form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
public ActionResult DisplayCustomer()
{
    Customer objCustomer = new Customer();

    objCustomer.Id = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["Customerid"]);
    objCustomer.CustomerCode = Request.Form["code"];
    objCustomer.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["amount"]);
    return View(objCustomer);
}
```

This is my action in controller(MVC 2 aspx):

```
<form action="DisplayCustomer" method="post">
    Customer id:-
    <input type="text" id="Customerid" /><br />
    Customer Code:-
    <input type="text" id="code" /><br />
    Customer amount:-
    <input type="text" id="amount" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="click here" />
</form>
```

This is the view. When someone hit the submit button it is directed to a new page:

```
<div>
   <b> ID</b> <%= Model.Id %><br />
   <b> Code </b><%=Model.CustomerCode %><br />
   <b> Amount</b> <%=Model.Amount %><br />
</div>
```

I always get 0 in Id and Amount while blank in CustomerCode.

Any clue? Why this is happening? What is wrong?

Comment: You're misusing ASP.Net MVC.  You need to use model binding and HTML helpers.

Comment: Yes use model binding your action methods would not be testable if you pull data from request form. MVC is designed keeping in mind TDD. Use`name=`"Customerid`"` as suggested by Aristos. IF you use model to render the view, view engine will take care of this by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue here is that you set the `id`, and not the `name`. Set the name to get the post back value. Eg:

```
<input type="text" name="Customerid" />
```

read also: [HTML input - name vs. id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id)  in the line "Used on form elements to submit information"

Comment: @shaleen You are welcome. I do not know if you have made a design error here as Slaks say, because I am not work with mvc. I only know that this is the reason that you not get the form values as I see your code.