# Form post data to ASHX hidden fields

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I have next form and some ashx

```
 <form action="FileUpload.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmUpload">
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" />
        <input id="viewId" type="hidden" />
        <input id="moduleId" type="hidden" />
        <button id="btnUpload" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

I can get file inside of   *ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)*
   context.Request.Files - file containe file information, but context.Request.Form["viewId"] is empty. 
That should I do to get hidden fields values ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `name="viewid"` also. The `name` attribute is used when you make post, not the `id`

read also: [HTML input - name vs. id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id)  in the line "Used on form elements to submit information"