# PHP dynamically created checkboxes with JQuery .toggle()

Tags: php, jquery, dynamically-generated

I have dynamically created an array of checkboxes in PHP for a form, but I don't want the Submit button to appear unless at least one checkbox is checked. Scouring the Internet most people who want the Submit button to only appear after checking a checkbox only have one "I agree" checkbox. Is it the dynamic creation that is preventing my script working?

PHP↴

```
// Dynamically create checkboxes from database
function print_checkbox($db){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM hue_flag') as $row) {
        if ($i == 0 || $i == 3 || $i== 6 || $i == 9){
            echo '<br><br>';
        }
        $i++;
        echo '<span class="'.$row['1'].'"><label for="'.$row['1'].'">'.ucfirst($row['1']).'</label><input type="checkbox" name="hue[]" id="hue" value="'.$row['0'].'"></span> ';
    }
}
```

jQuery↴

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hue[]').click(function(){
        $('#input_gown').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP function call↴

```
<?php print_checkbox($conn_normas_boudoir);?>
```

Admittedly I know nothing about jQuery or JavaScript and am still learning PHP. So, if there's a better way to implement this, let me know.

Comment: +1 for use of ↴ :)  Also my first guess is the square brackets are conflicting with the jquery selector engine, but I'll have to dig a little deeper to be sure

Comment: Never mind, you are using the ID selector but passing the input name.. I'd type an answer but I guess this is being pointed out by much faster typers than I as you read this

Comment: You're giving all your checkboxes the same ID. That's not allowed; IDs have to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving all your checkboxes the same ID. That's not allowed; IDs have to be unique.

An easy solution to both problems is to assign all the checkboxes a common class:

```
    echo '<span class="'.$row['1'].'"><label for="'.$row['1'].'">'.ucfirst($row['1']).'</label><input type="checkbox" name="hue[]" class="hue" value="'.$row['0'].'"></span> ';
```

Then select the class in jQuery:

```
$('.hue').change(function(){
    $('#input_gown').toggle();
});
```

But that may give unexpected results; what if two checkboxes are checked? The `#input_gown` element will toggle on and off again. Perhaps you only want it shown if *at least one* checkbox is checked:

```
$('.hue').change(function(){
    var val = false;
    $('.hue').each(function() {
        val = val || $(this).is(':checked'); // any checked box will change val to true
    });
    $('#input_gown').toggle(val); // true=show, false=hide
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/AyY3Z/

Comment: I see. I thought id was supposed to be the same as name. I guess I should have read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id) first. I'll try out your recommendation.

Comment: Sorry, did you rewrite .click to .change because change is a more basic level of the same effect?

Comment: I followed your code verbatim, but the button just remains hidden. How do I go about error checking jQuery?

Comment: Whoops, forgot a `$`. fixed.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I was trying to avoid javaScript for this project, but it looks like I'll need to add that to my plate pretty soon. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector is looking for elements with id `hue[]`.  But your elements have the id of just `hue`.

Change this:↴

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hue[]').click(function(){
        $('#input_gown').toggle();
    });
});
```

to this (IDs should really always be unique, and the square brackets will need to be escaped to work with the selector engine), ([a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SMEh7/1/))):↴

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=hue\\[\\]]').click(function(){
        $('#input_gown').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution. I suppose I should remove the id tag altogether, though.

Comment: You only need an ID attribute if you plan on accessing or styling (there is a valid argument to avoid ID style selectors) elements directly.  Blazemonger's approach will also work, but bind to input name I think is most semantically correct with minimal HTML, but that is just me

Comment: Oh really? I thought binding it to the name looked like a work around. I'll keep it in mind in future when I read up on jQuery. Thanks again.