# Upload multiple files where upload has ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page which has multiple file upload inputs whcih have ID's and Names relevant to the document type being uploaded which look like:

```
<input type="file" name="postedFile_37" id="37">
<input type="file" name="postedFile_23" id="23">
```

In my controller, how can I identify the name or id of the upload so I can assign a document to the type being uploaded in the DB?

I can see for example that if I do

```
Request.Files[i]
```

I can see the name of the index but I can't get the value to save out. How can I get either the name or ID from the posted file upload?

Comment: c# is a little broad. Web Forms? MVC? Something else?

Comment: I would guess at MVC, "In my controller" ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding hidden fields next to each of the files so you have two arrays - first is file itself and second is id.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fileId" value="37" />
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="hidden" name="fileId" value="38" />
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

.

```
public ActionResult Test (string[] fileId, List<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var f in file)
    {
        var id = fileId[i]; // this is your file id, f is file
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did think about doing this but wondered if there was a way of getting the ID off the upload. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible by HTML standards. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ASP.NET FileUpload control instead of the plain HTML control, you can access them individually (by ID) in the PostBack.

Comment: I'm using MVC Razor I don't really want to mix webforms and mvc If I can help it.