# Javascript setting Maximum & Minimum Answers

Tags: javascript, calculator

I need to ensure the minimum answer is 5 and the maximum can be no larger than 25. The code I use is:

```
function temp(form)
{
    var i = parseFloat(form.Inc.value, 10);
    var c = 0;
    c = 25 - ((300 - i) * 8.0 / 100);
   form.Fee.value = c.toFixed(2);

   function decrease(form)
   {
        if (c > 25) 
        {
           c--;
           document.getElementById('Fee').innerHTML = 25;
        }
   }

   function increase(form)
   {
       if (c < 5) 
       {
           c++;
           document.getElementById('Fee').innerHTML = 5;
       }
   }
}
```

However the answer box in the form doesn't recognise the minimum and maximum figures.

Comment: You should add some more explanation. As it stands I have almost no clue, what this code is intended to do.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise.

Comment: @Sirko The code enables a person to put a value (i) into a form which then calculates the answer. the fo=rmula for the equation is:The value (i) is a weekly income amount and the answer is the fee (c) charged.

Comment: The formula for the answer is:c = 25 - ((300 - i) * 8.0 / 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form.Fee.value implies that your form has an element named "Fee".
[The "name" attribute is different from the "id" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id), and as you've likely not given your form elements 'id's, document.getElementById() is presumably returning null.
Consider using document.getElementsByName or using form.Fee.

Additionally, the decrease() and increase() methods aren't being invoked.
I think you're looking for code like this:

```
 function temp(form)
 {
    var i = parseFloat(form.Inc.value, 10);
    var c = 0;
    c = 25 - ((300 - i) * 8.0 / 100);

    // Alternatively use Math.min and Math.max
    if ( c > 25 ) c = 25; 
    if ( c < 5 ) c = 5;

    form.Fee.value = c.toFixed(2);
 }
```

Additional notes; `var c` can be initialized with the expression in the line right below it; the initialization to 0 is unnecessary.