# Radio Button validation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery validation on text field which is working fine but when I apply it on radio button then it don't work. I don't know where I'm wrong.

my HTML and jQuery code is,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="2">

var name= jQuery('#name').val();
var gender= jQuery('#gender').val();
if(name.length == 0){
    var error = true;
    jQuery('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
    }else{
    jQuery('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
}
if(gender.value == 0){
    var error = true;
    jQuery('#gender_error').fadeIn(500);
    }else{
    jQuery('#gender_error').fadeOut(500);
}
```

Comment: unique html id please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender2" value="2">

var gender1=  jQuery('input[id=gender1]:checked').val()
    var gender2=  jQuery('input[id=gender2]:checked').val()

    if(!($("input[id='gender1']").prop("checked"))){
        if(!($("input[id='gender1']").prop("checked"))){
        var error = true;
        jQuery('#gender_error').fadeIn(500);  

        } else { jQuery('#gender_error').fadeOut(500); }

    } else {
        jQuery('#gender_error').fadeOut(500);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get Radio value,

```
var gender =  jQuery('input[name=gender]:checked').val();


if(!jQuery('input[name=gender]').is(":checked")){
    var error = true;
    jQuery('#gender_error').fadeIn(500);
    }else{
    jQuery('#gender_error').fadeOut(500);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't allow me to submit form until i choose radio button, but when i dont choose button it doesn't show me any error

Comment: yes its working but I want to show the error also if the user left the radio button blank. so what should I put in this line "if(gender.value == 0){
  var error = true;"

Comment: Updated Answer can you please check

Comment: It doesnt work still, I solved it and post my answer as well. Thank you so much for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use same `ID's` for multiple elements.**

**HTML:-**

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="2">
```

**JS:-**

`$("input[name=gender]:checked").val()`

Answer (score 1):

because both of your radio button have the same id, Id must be unique. If you want to check radio button clicked or not then try:

```
$("input[name=gender]").is(":checked")
```

another thing one of radio button always be clicked so you dont need to validate it, but you need to check male or female.

to set default check:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" checked="checked" value="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using same `ID`s multiple times. `ID`s cannot be same. They must be unique.

Use `prop()` to detect if radio button is checked or not. It returns boolean value.

JS:

```
$('#name_error,#gender_error').fadeOut();
var name = jQuery('#name').val();    
if (name.length == 0) {
    jQuery('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
}
if(!($("input[name='gender']").prop("checked"))){
    $('#gender_error').fadeIn(500);
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/8sWSQ/3)

Comment: you are using name of the field then whats the problem if I use same ID, I think it doesn't matter

Comment: Brush up your HTML basics. [This link might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id)

Comment: I solved it and posted my answer also, your idea really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want validate Checkboxes and ridiobuttons use jquery is() and validate :checked parameter

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="2">

var name= jQuery('[name=name]');    
var gender= jQuery('[name=gender]');
if(!name.is(':checked')){
    var error = true;
    jQuery('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
}else{
    jQuery('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
}
if(!gender.is(':checked')){
    var error = true;
    jQuery('#gender_error').fadeIn(500);
}else{
    jQuery('#gender_error').fadeOut(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="2">

<script>
var checked = $('.gender:checked');
if(checked.length == 0) {
    var error = true;
    $('#gender_error').fadeIn(500);
} else {
    $('#gender_error').fadeOut(500);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the same id **gender** in 2 elements  its wrong. 
Try to change:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name">
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="2">

var name= jQuery('#name').val();
var gender= jQuery('.gender').val();
if(name.length == 0){
    var error = true;
    jQuery('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
    }else{
    jQuery('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
}
if(gender.value == 0){
    var error = true;
    jQuery('#gender_error').fadeIn(500);
    }else{
    jQuery('#gender_error').fadeOut(500);
```