# Updating an html "value" with a jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i'm building a messaging application in which a user clicks on a button, a jquery prompt is displayed asking for the user to type in their message, and then ideally the message is sent using a separate ajax function.

Here is the code in question:

jQuery message prompt function:

```
        function getInput() {
         var text = prompt("Enter message", "");

            if (text != null) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text; //failed attempt at updating the value just using the id of the input. 
            }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form name="messagesend" method="post" onsubmit="return sendMessage(this);">   
<input type="hidden" id="demo" name="message" value="I want to update this field with the result of the javascript text variable" />
<input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Volume-Vibrate" onclick="getInput()"/>
</form>
```

As you can see, the field I want to update is the string contained in `value` which is the message being sent. How could I get that to update with the result of whatever the user puts in the text prompt?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Updated jQuery function to the following:

```
        function getInput() {
         var text = prompt("Enter message", "");

            if (text != null) {
                $("#demo").val(text);
            }
    }
```

This may be a different question, but when the button that is created in the HTML I originally posted is clicked, it displays the prompt and I type in a message, but the default value that I placed is still the message being sent. Is

```
onsubmit="return sendMessage(this);"
```

Being executed before the jQuery is updating the value field? And if so, is there anyway to fix that?

If it helps, here is `sendMessage` which uses ajax to send off the message to a php script.
The HTML `value` field (which I'm trying to get to be the user-input string from the jQuery prompt using `getInput()`) becomes the `data` variable, which also contains the registration id of the designated recipient of the message.

```
        function sendMessage(formObj){
            var data = $(formObj).serialize();
            $(formObj).unbind('submit');                
            $.ajax({
                url: "send_message.php",
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                      $('.txt_message').val("");
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Please provide the code for `sendMessage()`, and particularly, in what way does it call `getInput()`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't notice `getInput` was called in the button's `onclick` event. Just remove the event handler, and call `getInput` directly from `sendMessage` (of course before the `serialize` call), that should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A HTML field doesn't have inner HTML (the tag is self-closing), it has a *value* (and a `value` property).

But as you're using jQuery, you should use its functions anyway: `$("#demo").val(text)`

Answer (score 1):

As @Lucas has mentioned, `$("#demo").val(text)` works (see the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/))

Another way of doing the same thing (referencing the input field by name):
`$('input[name="demo"]').val()`

However, a name does not need to be unique, while an id should be unique (see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7470325)). It would be safer to add `id="demo"` to your input name - overkill in this case, but good practice.