# How to handle multiple inputs of the same type in a html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Let's say I've got a form in which you can describe a family:

```
<input type="text" name="mother">
<input type="text" name="father">
<input type="text" name="child">
```

But I want people to be able to add an infinite number of children to the form. So I can use Javascript to simply continue adding new inputs for more children, but I wonder how I should name these. Do I simply do `child1`, `child2`, `child3`, etc.? And on the backend I simply loop over all the children?

And what if all children also need an "age" input field. Do I simply continue adding fields such as `child1_age`, `child2_age`, `child3_age`?

I guess this would work, but I have the feeling that there's a smarter way of this. Does anybody know of a better way to handle this? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML forms can use arrays as input names. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="child[]">
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this discussion. Introduce the `id` attribute and keep the `name` attribute constant.

[HTML input - name vs. id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id)