# Textarea value is NULL javascript

Tags: javascript, php, textarea

I want to display the text area value. I generate it with PHP code
This code is in the looping

```
 for($i=0;$i<$piecount;$i++)
    {
    echo "<tr><td class=\"forma\" align=\"center\">".$compc[$i]."</td>";
    if($i==0)
    {
       echo "<td align=\"center\" class=\"forma\" rowspan=".$pcg."  style=\"\"> 
      <textarea name=\"eva\" id=\"evatext\"   class=\"textEva\" >
      </textarea> 
      <input type=\"image\"src=\"image/save.jpg\"class=\"imgClass\" onclick=\"EvaCek();\" name=\"save\"></td></tr>";
```

}
}

Also I have a html code for dummy my id for inputdate which is displayed none

```
<input name="evadate" id="inputdate" style="display:none">
```

And I pass it to javascript

```
function EvaCek()
{
    var dateobj = new Date();
        var month = dateobj.getUTCMonth()+1;
        var day = dateobj.getUTCDate();
        var year = dateobj.getUTCFullYear();
        var tes=document.getElementById("inputdate").innerHTML= year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
        var bla=document.getElementById("evatext").value;

    if(bla!="")
    {
     alert(tes);
     alert(bla);

    }
```

}

When I type something into the text area and save it, it does the alert, but only the date, the text area is NULL. What is wrong in here? Thank you

Comment: Try putting the `PHP` output in as `HTML` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: check your "name" attributes match your "id" attributes so that getElementById are aligned. Also, use your browser's console to read errors rather than using alert, it'll save you tons of time. to do so open "developer tools" in your browser to see the console, then use console.log(tes) instead of alert(tes)

Comment: @Nick. Ah it works. something wrong with the php ?

Comment: Problem Solved @Elbert ?

Comment: @Nana Not yet. The first text area does the alert when given an input. The other dont

Comment: Because you are accessing with ID. **ID Must Be Unique**. Check my answer. @Elbert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because ID should be unique for each input.

**IDs must be unique**

For more info, check here [Unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id)

So, access it through class name. I'm not seeing anywhere `'inputdate'`. So, i didn't edited it. But, Don't access `inputdate` or `textarea` through `ID`.
Because, `forloop` is creating numerous number of `<textarea></textarea>` and every `textarea` is having the **same id**. **Avoid accessing with ID**.

```
<?
for($i=0;$i<$piecount;$i++)
{
    echo "<tr><td class=\"forma\" align=\"center\">".$compc[$i]."</td>";
    if($i==0)
    {
        echo "<td align=\"center\" class=\"forma\" rowspan=".$pcg."  style=\"\"> 
            <textarea name=\"eva\" id=\"evatext\" class=\"textEva\" ></textarea> 
            <input type=\"image\"src=\"image/save.jpg\"class=\"imgClass\" onclick=\"EvaCek();\" name=\"save\">
        </td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
?>

<?
function EvaCek()
{
  var dateobj = new Date();
      var month = dateobj.getUTCMonth()+1;
      var day = dateobj.getUTCDate();
      var year = dateobj.getUTCFullYear();
            //change for inputdate. Access it through class name.
      var tes=document.getElementByClass("inputdate").innerHTML= year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
      var bla=document.getElementByClass("textEva").value;

  if(bla!="")
  {
   alert(tes);
   alert(bla);

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: It works. but after using getElementByTagName :). Thanks

Comment: Glad. It worked. Yeah TagName is also one option. Thanks @Elbert

Answer (score 1):

use this to get value of text area ...[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/cnq8daut/)

```
document.getElementById("evatext").innerHTML;
```

full code

```
function EvaCek()
{
    var dateobj = new Date();
    var month = dateobj.getUTCMonth()+1;
    var day = dateobj.getUTCDate();
    var year = dateobj.getUTCFullYear();
    var tes=document.getElementById("inputdate").innerHTML= year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
    var bla=document.getElementById("evatext").innerHTML;// use this

    if(bla!="")
    {
     alert(tes);
     alert(bla);

    }
}
```

Comment: are u echoing or typing anything in between  text-area or no..??

Comment: try using `document.getElementById("evatext").text;`