# instant search with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
Start searching: <input id="search" type="text" size="30" >
<div id="search_results"></div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
</id>
</form>

<?php
$searchname=$_POST["search"];
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","landryr","landryr","landryr");
 // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$titles = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from actor where <mainactorID> LIKE '%$searchname%'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($titles)) {
    $result[] = $row['mainactorID'];
}
?>
```

why is ssearchname not recognized as a variable?? my only problem is that 
"Undefined index: search in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 3". please please please help.

Comment: `<input id="search" type="text" size="30" >`  -> `<input id="search" name="search" type="text" size="30" >` note the addition of the `name` attribute

Comment: @cmorrissey - Good catch, I didn't even see the form all the way up there -__-

Comment: `where <mainactorID>` that isn't your real syntax, *is it?*

Comment: I don't see the use for jQuery here. You're not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
<input id="search" name="search" type="text" size="30" >
```

Have a look here: [HTML Input Name Vs ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id)

Comment: Question is: *why* should they?

Comment: Updated answer - cheers :)