# PHP mail function not working on click

Tags: php, email, onclick

I'm trying to create a simple form that when filled out sends me a specific email. The website definitely registers the click and tells me that my message was sent, but no email ever comes.

If I, however, get rid of the if-statement, it does send me an email, but only when I refresh the page, so it doesn't send me any of the relevant information. So, my if-statement is wrong, but when I change it to `strlen($name)!=0`, it still doesn't send me the email.

I think the problem is that when I click the button, it doesn't run the php code. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <div id="success"></div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
    </div>
</div>
 <?php
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $phone=$_POST["phone"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $message=$message."\nSent by".$name." whose phone number is ".$phone."and whose email is".$email;
        mail("myemail@gmail.com","title","let's try this message.".$message);
    }
?>
```

Comment: the button balise should have a name='submit' to be sended as <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>

Comment: @RmidiAyoub it is not the submit button that is the problem, but the other form elements -- see my answer

Comment: but he is calling a isset($_POST["submit"] which is not fuguring in the form !!

Comment: where is your </form tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$_POST` data elements use the `name` attribute, not the `id` attribute; change all the `id`s in the form to `name`.

For example:

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
```

should be:

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" name="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                                                  ^^^^
```

Now, the `$_POST["phone"]` should get  the right value. Do this for all of the other values.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7470407/2397327) for more details.

Comment: @JimmyKim No you're not! We all make mistakes! But I'm glad I helped (and don't forget to accept if I did)!