# Using GET as method on HTML form is not appending to the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web, get

I have the following form:

```
<form name="frmSearch" id="frmSearch" action="search_results.html" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtQuery" placeholder="What are you hungry for ?" required="true"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtLocation" placeholder="Your location" required="true">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="middle"><input type="submit"  placeholder="Let's Eat!" ></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

When I click on the 'Let's Eat' button(the submit button), URL of the new page launched does not include the values from the two input fields:

```
http://localhost:8000/search_results.html?
```

Why is this ?

Comment: Also helpful is [HTML input - name vs. id](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7470268/5743988)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `input`s need `name` attributes.

Comment: There are probably dozens of other questions that this could be closed as a duplicate of, but I can't find them.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I did a brief search but couldn't find the right set of keywords.