# What is "dsh" parameter in create google account form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to know, what is "dsh" parameter in below form? where can I get this param?

```
 <form novalidate="" id="gaia_loginform" action="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="service" id="service" value="blogger">
    <input type="hidden" name="dsh" id="dsh" value="-2655181513770911851">
    <input type="hidden" name="GALX" value="oBUZ5i4i_48">
 </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parameter"? The name/id attributes? If so, that's related to the POST array for it in your unknown PHP or the one you want us to write for you.

Comment: *"where can I get this param?"* - You write it. Plus, why was this tagged as javascript?

Comment: I want o know value of it, and where do I can create ?thank you

Comment: You've my answer below and you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The `name="dsh"` attribute is used in conjunction with a POST array in PHP.

Which is pulled from:

```
<?php 
$var = $_POST['dsh'];
echo $var;
```

The value from it is then (automatically) pulled from the hidden value for it,
being `value="-2655181513770911851"` since there is a preset value for it.

An `id` attribute is used either in conjunction with javascript/jQuery and/or CSS.

More on this:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id
- [HTML input - name vs. id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id)

Consult the following on PHP.net on working/dealing with forms:

- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

All this assuming you are running this under a working PHP environment. You cannot run this straight from your browser as `file:///` since that will not parse PHP directives.

NOTA: The "Google" stuff, is out of scope of this question.