# Is using name attribute deprecated in HTML5?

Tags: html

Should I use the `name` attribute only for form controls?
Is it deprecated today in HTML5?

I noticed similar questions are outdated, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#attributes-3 has the authoritative list of which attributes are allowed in HTML and which elements allow them.

Answer (score 12):

> Should I use the `name` attribute only for form controls?

No. It is only on `<a>` elements that it is obsolete (and replaced with `id` on any element).

The [attributes index](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1) in the HTML5 spec shows where it should still be used.

Some uses of it which were never standard should be replaced with `class`.

> Is it deprecated today in HTML5?

HTML5 doesn't use the term "deprecated". It describes it as [obsolete](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features).

Comment: In 2018, the attributes table is no longer present in that document. Aside from an  [archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20161116114534/https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1) you can find such a table now at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#attributes-3

Answer (score 5):

I checked Mozilla Developer Network ([MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs)) and found this:

> name

```
<button>, <form>, <fieldset>, <iframe>, <input>, <keygen>, <object>, <output>, <select>, <textarea>, <map>, <meta>, <param>
```

> Name of the element. For example used by the server to identify the
> fields in form submits.

So you should use this attribute only on these elements. Any other element with a `name` attribute is not correct. For more info about what attributes exists and where/who/why to use it check the full documentation:

*[HTML attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)*

Answer (score 4):

It seems that using `<a name="">` is depreciated - which means you shouldn't use it for your anchor tags.

On forms you should still use `name=""` to label your form controls - [AngularJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) requires you to use `name=""` if you ever want to use validation.

Some more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html).