# PHP form won't pass value to email anyone?

Tags: php, forms, email

For some odd reason, the business input value won't submit to the email... it's always blank.. can someone tell me what's wrong? Thank you!

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(isset(empty($_POST['submit'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['business'])  ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$business = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['business']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'somekoreanguy@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nBusiness: $business\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Business Name *" id="business" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your business name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

For some reason, when I put that  "empty($_POST['business'])  ||" in there, nothing comes in to the email. When I remove "type="text" from my business html section the email goes through but nothing as a value. it'll just say Business: and blank....

Comment: need to seethe form, hope its using POST not GET

Comment: can you sent the form?

Comment: What's in the PHP error log?

Comment: @nogad I don't see POST or GET on my form... =/ where can I find it?

Comment: @mkaatman I don't see any error log... I tried attaching ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); to my code but nothing. I can't find PHP.ini file on my server to turn it on..

Comment: its get by default you need to set the action `action="POST"`

Comment: @nogad I'll try that and let you know! Thanks.

Comment: @nogad didn't work.. =/

Comment: sorry its method, not action

Comment: @nogad yup, I knew what you were talking about =)

Answer (score 0):

you did not define `method="post"`

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
```

so it will be like

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate method="post">
```

give name for

`<button type="submit" name ="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>`

So your code will be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
//set your code here
}
```

Comment: After doing what you posted it shows me a message saying that the mail service is not responding, please try later when I click the submit button.

Comment: I've updated the PHP and HTML code now to your changes.

Comment: The submit code is working now, the another problem is in your PHP mail code, I recommend you can use email plugin to handle your mail services
PHP mailer - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I'm still learning PHP and when I see a plugin, it doesn't process fully to me yet so when I learn a bit more I'll look into the plugins. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's always blank, because no `name=""` in your input form, `name=""` to reference form data after a form is submitted. Add `name=""` to your input like this..

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(trim($_POST['email'])== ''  || trim($_POST['phone'])== ''   || trim($_POST['business'])== ''  || trim($_POST['message'])== ''  || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "No arguments Provided!";
}else{
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$business = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['business']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'somekoreanguy@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nBusiness: $business\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>     
<body>
    <form name="contactForm" novalidate method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" name="name" id="name" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." required>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" name="email" id="email" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." required>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" name="phone" id="phone" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number." required>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Business Name *" name="business" id="business" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your business name." required>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" name="message" id="message" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message." required></textarea>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div name="success"></div>
            <button type="submit" name ="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but may I ask a question? what made you change the ID's to name? I would like to know the reason behind the decision you've made? Im still learning PHP.. Thank you!

Comment: Also, is it okay to give two names at the very top? sentMessage and contactForm?

Comment: After the changes, nothing happens when I press the submit button =/

Comment: You can use both id and name.
for more information about id and nama :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id

Comment: Thank you, I will check and let you know the result!