# Redirect to another html page using only html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html4

How to go to another page using only html and css. I have tried with

```
window.location.href="admin.html";
```

This statement not working.

```
<input type="text" value="Username" name="username" /><br>
<input type="text" value="Password" name="password" /><br>
<input type="button" value="Password" name="password" value="Log In" onClick="login()" /><br>

<script>
    function login() {
        var id = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
        if (id == "admin" && pass = "admin")
            //Redirect to admin page
        else if (id == "employee" && pass = "employee")
        //Redirect to employee page
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `using only html and css`, yet I see you try javascript?

Comment: `window.location.href="admin.html";` should work fine. Try providing a [mcve] of your problem. Check your browser's developer tools for error messages.

Comment: What does not working mean? What is the error on screen? In what directory have you placed admin.html?

Comment: By the way, it's a very bad idea to handle login with only Javascript like that (Security-wise reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have given the fields a `name`, not an `id` so your code will throw an error before reaching the redirect.
2. Is `admin.html` in the same scope/folder as this file? If not, you will need to specify the relative path to `admin.html`, eg: `../otherFolder/admin.html`
3. Have you tried using `window.location.replace(admin.html)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with the code you use to navigate. You never get that far.

Look at the developer tools in your browser. Examine the Console. You should see an error message like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

`document.getElementById("username")` fails to find your element because **you have no element with that id**. The [`name` and the `id` are different attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id) and are not freely interchangable.

You have the same problem for the password field.

Comment: Sorry, It'll be
<input type="text" value="Username" id="username" /><br>
<input type="text" value="Password" id="password" /><br>
<input type="button"  value="Log In" onClick="login()" /><br>