# selecting key-attributes for posts in python-selects

Tags: python-requests

For example `username` and `password` in

```
r = requests.post( loginUrl, data = {'username':'myuser', 'password':'mypw'} )
```

are from attribute `name` on the web site element. The information to `post` is given in parameter `data` with a dictionary.
It has a key `username` with a value `myuser`. The key `username` is taken from an element on a website with attribute `name`, means the key is taken from a key-value. By default `requests` select attribute `name` for the key.

To clarify this here is a html code snippet:

```
<form name="login" id="form1" method="post" action="http://mylogin.net">
  Username: <input name="username" id="input1" type="text" /><br/>
  Password: <input name="password" id="input2" type="password" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

I prefer to use the `id` attribute as key because it is unique on the web page.

How can I select attribute `id` instead of default `name` to get the key for the post in `requests`, so I can use

```
r = requests.post( loginUrl, data = {'input1':'myuser', 'input2':'mypw'} ) ?
```

Comment: all servers expect value from `name`, not from `id` - so you can't use `'input1':'myuser'` - you have to use `'username':'myuser'`.

Comment: btw: use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox (tab `Network`) to see all requests send from browser to server and you will see that browser uses `'username'`, not `'input1'`. It doesn't send full `<form>` but only some values so you will not see `'input1'` in POST request.

Comment: @furas Ah yes, I see. That give me the idea to google with the right keywords. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I learned from the discussion there is no solution. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1397618) that the `name` attribute is required for sending data to the server.

> Use name attributes for form controls (such as `<input>` and `<select>`), as that's the identifier used in the POST or GET call that happens on form submission.