# Sending data from html on server (node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a problem with sending data on the server. I run server.js in node but always after clicking submit button  req.body.username and req.body.password is undefinied... HTML file is opened in a browser, so probably it is the problem, but I have no idea how to solve it. I'm a beginner so be understanding...

index.html:

```
<form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/">   
<fieldset>
<label for="username"></label>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username">
<label for="password"></label>

<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password">

<input type="submit" value="Create user">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

server.js:

```
 const express = require('express');
 const mysql = require('mysql');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 const http = require('http');

 const template = require('./template'); 
 const app = express();

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
 app.use(express.static('public'))
 app.use(bodyParser());

 app.post('/',(req, res) => {



  template.createUser( 

    req.body.username,
    req.body.password
  )

 });

 app.listen(3000, 'localhost' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `name` attributes to your form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username"></label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username">
        <label for="password"></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Create user">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

See this answer for more info: [HTML input - name vs. id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id)