# Hiding/Unhiding the <div> block according to option value in <select> tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the  block according to the selected Option and other remaining  should be hidden.But i am not getting the output as desired.Just the options are shown but their related div content is not shown.I am new to Javascript.How can handle this?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('a').click) {
        document.getElementById('displayA').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('b').click){
      document.getElementById('displayB').style.display = 'block';
    } 
     else if (document.getElementById('c').click){
      document.getElementById('displayC').style.display = 'block';
    } 
    else{

      document.getElementById('displayD').style.display = 'block';
    
    }

}

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <select>
  <option onclick="javascript:yesNocheck();" name="b" id="a" value="a">A</option>
  <option onclick="javascript:yesNocheck();" name="b" id="b" value="b">B</option>
  <option onclick="javascript:yesNocheck();" name="b" id="b" value="b">C</option>
  <option onclick="javascript:yesNocheck();" name="b" id="b" value="b">D</option>
</select>
    <div id="displayA" style="display:none">
        A is clicked
    </div>

    <div id="displayB" style="display:none">
        B is clicked
    </div>

    <div id="displayC" style="display:none">
        C is clicked
    </div>

    <div id="displayD" style="display:none">
        D is clicked
    </div>
        
       
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('a').click` is not a thing.  `click` is a method, not an attribute.

Comment: Look in to using the `change` event of the `select`. Putting click events on `option` elements is a bad idea for a variety of reasons. Honestly there's so many issues here that I'd suggest you break the tasks down and research them individually. I've also marked this question with several duplicates for you to read through and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below,

- For `Select` you should use [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event and you don't need to add it for every option instead with select.
- For HTML Elements `Id` should be Unique but the name can be same. Chere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id)

Here in the example,

- Have used [class selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) to hide all the `div` on load and all the elements which are assigned class name `.disp` are hidden on load.
- Assigned the onchange event for Select and will be called each time when the option changed.
- Passed the [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp) object to the event and from which the value can be fetched inside the `yesNocheck` function.
- Based on the value, provided with the simple logic and the particular div can be shown.
- [querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) will select all the elements matching the filter and here in the case applied for hiding the other `Div's`

```js
function yesNocheck(thisObj) {

var val = thisObj.value;

console.log(val);

document.querySelectorAll('.disp').forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.display = "none";
});

document.getElementById("display"+ val.toUpperCase() +"").style.display = 'block';

}
```

```css
.disp
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <select onchange="yesNocheck(this)">
  <option name="b" id="a" value="a">A</option>
  <option name="b" id="b" value="b">B</option>
  <option name="b" id="c" value="c">C</option>
  <option name="b" id="d" value="d">D</option>
</select>
    <div id="displayA" class="disp">
        A is clicked
    </div>

    <div id="displayB" class="disp">
        B is clicked
    </div>

    <div id="displayC" class="disp">
        C is clicked
    </div>

    <div id="displayD" class="disp">
        D is clicked
    </div>
        
       
</body>

</html>
```