# getElementsByName() javascript

Tags: javascript

Please pardon my extreme naivety......I am trying to execute a javascript using the getElementByName method, but essentially, when I get to the site I want 0 to be entered in the quantity field (after 15 seconds of getting to said site).

This is what I get when I inspect the quantity field -

`<input type ="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="3">`

```
function emptylocation() {

    var myVar = setInterval(emptylocation, 15000);

    (document.getElementByName("quantity")[0].value = 0)
    (document.getElementByName("quantity")[1].value = 0)
    (document.getElementByName("quantity")[2].value = 0)
    (document.getElementByName("quantity")[3].value = 0)
    (document.getElementByName("quantity")[4].value = 0)
    (document.getElementByName("quantity")[5].value = 0)
}
```

Comment: you need an `s`: `getElementsByName`, also, your `setInterval` function will create a new internal every time your functions runs (which happens every 15 seconds)

Comment: getElements not getElement

Comment: I have added the s and it's still not executing. I don't know this is as a result of using getElementsByName as opposed to getElemenetsByID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
var quantities = document.getElementsByName("quantity");
for(var i=0; i < quantities.length; i++) 
    quantities[i].value = 0;
}
```

It might also be better to use ID instead of name for such things.

Comment: Thanks sir - I actually planned on using ID, but when I inspected element, I didn't see ID

Comment: @Code_Guess that was just a suggestion btw. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7470407/2522616) answer for more details.

Comment: thanks so much, that really helped me...... Is it possible to do a for loop using the the document.querySelector? So, on this same page, I want the same javascript to cilck the "update quantity" button after inputting the number 0... There are multiple "update quantity" buttons on the page with the same input type

Comment: @Code_Guess Sorry, I don't think I understand that completely. Can you give a tiny example of what you are trying to achieve and I can try to help you more? Btw, you can also upvote and mark correct answers ;)

Comment: I have a web page that has a list of various items. I go into this location regularly to empty it out by inputting 0 in the quantity field and then click an "update quantity" button, this process is/has to be done item by item. There are multiple quantity field and "update qty" buttons with the same element properties

Comment: Oh okay, so you can have two types of buttons "Update Quantity' button like you already do which updates 1 textbox. AND you can make another button like "Update All" and use the code that I posted, which will update all the text fields with `name=quantity` to 0.

Comment: How do I go about creating the "Update All" button and make it do the action of updating the the quantities to 0?

Answer (score 1):

### `document.getElementsByName()`

An old method that has unexpected results in an edge case involving `for` loops. Instead use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)<sup>*</sup> which is the Swiss Army<sup>TM</sup> knife of DOM methods. Replace the following methods on the left with the methods on the right:

```
  <article class='x' name='x'></article>
  // ... Any amount of DOM elements that meet specific traits

  document.getElementsByClassName('x') /* ------> */ document.querySelectorAll('.x')
  document.getElementsByName('x') /* -----------> */ document.querySelectorAll('[name=x]')
  document.getElementsByTagName('article') /* --> */ document.querySelectorAll('article')
```

<sup>* Also see this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)</sup>

### [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms) & [`.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)

If these DOM elements are form controls (aka fields -- ex. `<input>`, `<select></select>`, etc), and are within a `<form></form>` (which they should be, although still valid without a `<form></form>`) -- `.forms` and `.elements` properties can be used:

```
<form id='x'>
  <input name='z'>
  // ... Any amount of fields with the name of 'z' (ie ['name=z'])
</form>

// Reference form#x
const fx = document.forms.x
// Reference all form controls within form#x
const fc = fx.elements
// Reference all form controls with ['name=z'] within form#x
const fz = fc.z

/* OR */
/* The above statements in one line */
const fXCZ = document.forms.x.elements.z
```

---

#### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**

```js
//~~[1]~~
/* Reference DOM Elements *///

//1a. 
/* Example 1 */
// Reference all fields within form#example1
const exp1 = document.forms.example1.elements;
/*
Collect all input[name=quantity] within form#example1 into a HTML Collection
*/
const qty1 = exp1.quantity;

//1b. 
/* Example 2 */
// Reference form#example2
const exp2 = document.getElementById('example2');
/*
Collect all input within form#example2 into a NodeList 
*/
const qty2 = exp2.querySelectorAll('input');

//~~[2]~~
/* Define Function *///

//2.
/*
@Params collection -- An array-like object of fields (ex. qty1 or qty2)
        dataString -- A String assigned to each field - defaults to "0" 
                      if not specified
*/
function changeValue(collection, dataString = "0") {
  collection.forEach(field => field.value = dataString);
}

//~~[3]~~
/* Invoke setTimeout() *///

//3a.
/* Example 1 */
setTimeout(function() {
  changeValue(qty1, '0');
}, 15000);

//3b.
/* Example 2 */
setTimeout(function() {
  changeValue(qty2);
}, 15000);
```

```html
<form id='example1'>
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
</form>
<hr>
<form id='example2'>
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
  <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" size="3">
</form>
```