# Submitting form to two different actions in two different controllers asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have googled a lot about this question but couldn't find any help regarding my scenario. So, here is the question 
I have a form containing a single drop down, named **Sections**, user can select a **Section** and then user have **two** choices.
**1-Add File to this Section By Going To File Uploading Form**
**2-Add Further Subsection By Going to Add Section Form**
[This is image of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSnO6.png)

[image]

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SectionForm","Sections"))
    {
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DisplayFor(s => s.SectionName)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.SelectedSection, new SelectList(Model.Sections,"SectionId","SectionName"),"Select a Section",new {@class = "form-control",autofocus="autofocus"} )
    </div>
    <p>
        If you don't see your desired section here, Click <strong>Add Section</strong>.
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Further Subsection</button>

      <br />
     <a href="@Url.Action("FileForm","LawFiles",new { sectionId =  Model.SelectedSection })" class="btn btn-primary">Add File</a>
}
<br>
```

**SectionForm** and **FileForm** are my actions and **Sections** and **LawFiles** are controllers.
**anchor tag** at the end won't work until I don't submit the form

Comment: Thanks for edit @Yogi

Comment: remove ***anchor tag*** from ***form*** scope. add it after form closing bracket..

Comment: yeah in actual code it is out of form scope.

Comment: then post actual code here..

Comment: it is the actual code sir. I was unable to understand how stackoverflow posts code. so its a little mistake.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21153895/795683

Comment: I have read these articles while searching sir. Mostly are for Submit and Cancel which goes to single action within single controller.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to modify the action of your form. You’ll add a click event on the submit button and overwrite the default submit action.

```
 <html>
 <body>
    <form id="myform">
           <input type="submit" id="submit1"/>
           <input type="submit" id="submit2"/>
    </form>
 </body>
 <script>
    $("#submit1").click(function() {
    document.myform.action = “http://localhost/controller/action1”;
    });
    $("#submit2").click(function() {
      document.myform.action = “http://localhost/controller/action2”; 
    });
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think its not a good approach , providing url's and strings.