# What is going on in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I don't know if there is any easy answer to this, but can anyone give me any idea why my site is totally crapping out in IE8? Is there something relatively easy that I can address to make it not become a complete mess?

Or at least any area to start investigating where similar problems tend to crop up in IE8?

Thanks!

http://firewalkcreative.com/2012/

Comment: If you are going to make us go to the site, at least make sure it doesn't timeout. Can't get to it from my browser and the w3's validator service can't reach it either (which is the first thing I usually suggest for a vague question like this).

Comment: site was fine when I posted, and right now all my godaddy sites seem to be down...this is the final straw and I am officially moving to a new hosting company..sorry about this

Comment: [WinHost](http://www.winhost.com/a/kuruol_b_5) > GoDaddy (yes, that's my affiliate link)

Comment: I got -6 points because godaddy got hacked between me posting this, and people reading the post..bummer :-( Well, looks like the site is finally back up now..

Comment: I edited the post to unlock it so people could reverse downvotes (and I undid mine) since that was completely not your fault. **However**, you still should provide more details about your problem in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Start by viewing and fixing [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://firewalkcreative.com/2012/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). The most critical errors are often structural ones, like an unclosed tag. While it's good practice to fix non-structural errors (such as the one you mentioned in [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888773/what-is-the-correct-alternative-for-the-attribute-name)), browsers are forgiving if you get the basic structure right.

The bigger culprit (but don't neglect fixing validation errors) is that you are using HTML 5 tags which IE8 knows nothing about like `section` and `header`. Thus, the CSS styles aren't applied to those tags. [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/) will easily fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it was using html5, then got a timeout upon refresh. Without being able to access the site I can't tell you exactly, but html5 and ie8 are going to cause problems (most of the time) unless you use a workaround like a .js plugin.

I frequently use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)